# realm objectForPrimaryKey can not found my object in database

Tags: swift, realm

I define a class named User And set it's primaryKey 'userId' like this:

```
class User: Object {

    var userId = 0
    var name = "haha"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userId"
    }    
}
```

then I write some data to defualt database, and I can find it with realm browser:

```
let user = User()
user.userId = 345
user.name = "哈哈"
print("\n\n" + NSHomeDirectory())

try! realm.write { 
    realm.add(user, update: true)
}
```

but in the end I use

```
let user = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(User.self, key: 345)
```

it got a object with userId = 0 and name = "haha"

ps: my english is not good,please use chinese if you can,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but i remember that we need to add dynamic before var like this:

```
class User: Object {

dynamic var userId = 0
dynamic var name = "haha"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userId"
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `realm.add(user, update: true)`, which will update an existing object. There's is no existing object, so nothing happens. Try `realm.add(user)`.

Comment: thx,I use The realm browser to see the database and the object is certainly existed.